# How to use Jest to monitor ES6 method calls?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Testing a class that calls a utilities class, with typescript. The goal is to mock the utilities class and test the data passed to the calls.

A class to test

```
import {Utils} from "~/src/play/utils";

export class Actions {
  constructor() {
}

async readFile(): Promise<void> {
   const utils = new Utils();
   await utils.action(5)
 }
}

const actions = new Actions();
actions.readFile()
```

Utilities class

```
export class Utils {
  constructor() {}

  async action(count: number): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(count);
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

Test script

```
// @ts-ignore
import {Utils} from "./utils";
import {Actions} from "~/src/play/actions";

const mockUtils = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../utils', () => {
  return {
    Utils: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            default: () => {return {utils: mockUtils}},
            action: () => {
                return 5;
            }
        }
    })
   }
})

describe('actions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    //  Utils.mockClear();
    mockUtils.mockClear();
  })

  test('success', async () => {
    const actions = new Actions()
    await actions.readFile()
    expect(mockUtils).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
  })
 })
```

It doesn't appear to be picking up the mock. The result is

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: 2

Number of calls: 0

at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jrobens/NetBeansProjects/azuron/winpay-uploader/src/play/__test__/actions.spec.ts:28:27)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Taking @Stanislav Šolc advice add the return and argument value, including async

```
// @ts-ignore
import {Utils} from "../utils";
import {Actions} from "../actions";

const mockUtils = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../utils', () => {
return {
    Utils: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            default: () => {return {utils: mockUtils}},
             action: (count: number): Promise<boolean> => {
                 console.log(count);
                 return Promise.resolve(true);
            }
        }
    })
}
})
```

The result doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to  mock `Utils.prototype.action()` method. Use [jest.restoreAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrestoreallmocks) restores all mocks back to their original value in `afterEach` hook. Prevent the value of mock from affecting other test cases.

E.g.

`actions.ts`:

```
import { Utils } from './utils';

export class Actions {
  constructor() {}

  async readFile(): Promise<void> {
    const utils = new Utils();
    await utils.action(5);
  }
}
```

`utils.ts`:

```
export class Utils {
  constructor() {}

  async action(count: number): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(count);
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

`actions.test.ts`:

```
import { Utils } from './utils';
import { Actions } from './actions';

describe('actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  test('success', async () => {
    const actionSpy = jest.spyOn(Utils.prototype, 'action').mockResolvedValueOnce(false);
    const actions = new Actions();
    await actions.readFile();
    expect(actionSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(5);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68879782/actions.test.ts (10.186 s)
  actions
    ✓ success (3 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   71.43 |      100 |      75 |   71.43 |                   
 actions.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 utils.ts   |   33.33 |      100 |      50 |   33.33 | 5-6               
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.827 s, estimated 11 s
```

Answer (score 0):

The module path in jest.mock() must be literally same as the path used to load a dependency in tested unit. This, by the way, is reason why tests are in same directory as tested unit (something you probably don't do).

and you must mock exact structure of module and of course asynchronous nature of methods as well. So in your case, you export constructor function with asynchronous action method. So something like this is better start.

```
jest.mock('~/src/play/utils', () => {
   return {
      Utils: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          return {action: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(5)};
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes. I am putting tests in __test__ and I do have to reference the tests using ../

Comment: I understand, i won't ask you why. You can mock('~/src/play/utils') module path for Actions tests and still have import './utils' in tests itself. Mock() just redirect any import with same path to factory. And i also like suggestion from @slideshowp2 to spyOn prototype of utils...

Comment: Following the documentation. https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring. I had it in __test__ instead of __tests__ and if I do ./util from within __tests__ I get Cannot find module './utils' from 'src/play/__tests__/actions.spec.ts'. Still does not match if I put it all in the same folder.

Comment: The @ts-ignore says that Utils is declared but never read. The tests, mocks, mock_data directory system seems to work with axios test (non-es6) but not here.